# 'NoneType' error when trying to set attributes for the first tag from a parsed PDF document in Python with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, css, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am writing a Python script using pdfminer.six to convert a huge bulk of pdfs to html to upload them on a e-store afterwards. So far the main text blocks have been parsed quite well, but in the process I had to replace all spans to divs (and strip the spans from their attributes) for obvious reasons, so now a document's structure is as follows:

```
<div> #first main block
    <div>
        Product desc heading
    </div>
    <div>
        Product desc text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>

<div> #second main block
    <div>
        Product specs heading
    </div>
    <div>
        Product specs text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>
```

The problem is the navigation in identical divs. If I try to find the very first div and add some attributes to it, like the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) suggest:

```py
firstdiv = soup.find('div')
firstdiv['class'] = 'main_productinfo'
```

The result is quite predictable - IDLE prints out the following error:

```py
File "C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1036, in __setitem__
    self.attrs[key] = value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

, since the `find()` method doesn't return a particular result (may or may not find).

I want to strain the first block in each file and then parse the tables (found in the specs block below) to html and join these two in each upload file.
How can I add attributes to the first tag without converting the soup to string again and again (and thus making it really, really ugly, since it converts the newly refined soup without any whitespaces) and replacing parts of the string in `str(soup)`? I'm quite new to Python and nothing readily comes to mind.

UPD:
I'm using Python 3.7.2 on Win 7 64.

Comment: can there be no div?

Comment: @QHarr The thing is, there is a div, it prints out just fine, but the value assignment doesn't work, treating the **found** div like if it wasn't there.

Comment: I did the same as @chittown in my deleted answer and also got the assignment. So I guess something else is at work with your actual data.

Comment: @QHarr Maybe because it's in a `for` loop that iterates over a number of files in a directory, not just a single file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting that error:

```
import bs4

html = '''<div> #first main block
    <div>
        Product desc heading
    </div>
    <div>
        Product desc text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>

<div> #second main block
    <div>
        Product specs heading
    </div>
    <div>
        Product specs text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

firstdiv = soup.find('div')
```

**Output:**

```
print (firstdiv)
<div> #first main block
    <div>
        Product desc heading
    </div>
<div>
        Product desc text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>
```

Then:

```
firstdiv['class'] = 'main_productinfo'
print (firstdiv)

<div class="main_productinfo"> #first main block
    <div>
        Product desc heading
    </div>
<div>
        Product desc text
    </div>
    #etc etc
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that's the point - `firstdiv` prints out fine, but the assignment doesn't work for me.

Comment: how is the html source code stored? in other words, where is the part of your code that you have stored `soup`? I see it above, not where you declare it.

Comment: It is stored in a string variable, where the original parsed result from pdfminer goes. Then this variable is fed into `soup`.

Comment: Are you using ‘html.parser’? Or ‘lxml’?

Comment: I'm using `html.parser`.